# How to print the list of employees who have joined on a particular month from an employee list?

Tags: java, hashmap

How to print the list of employees who have joined on a particular month from an employee list?

Hi, I am trying to print the list of employees who have joined on the month of suppose "June"?
Below is my code, 
Pojo class:-

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String empID;
    private Designation designation;
    private LocalDate dateOfJoining;
    private int monthlySalary;

    public Employee(String name, String empID, Designation designation, LocalDate dateOfJoining, int monthlySalary) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.empID = empID;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.dateOfJoining = dateOfJoining;
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }

    public Employee() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public Designation getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(Designation designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public LocalDate getDOJ() {
        return dateOfJoining;
    }

    public void setDOJ(LocalDate dOJ) {
        dateOfJoining = dOJ;
    }

    public int getMonthlySalary() {
        return monthlySalary;
    }

    public void setMonthlySalary(int monthlySalary) {
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((dateOfJoining == null) ? 0 : dateOfJoining.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((designation == null) ? 0 : designation.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((empID == null) ? 0 : empID.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + monthlySalary;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (dateOfJoining == null) {
            if (other.dateOfJoining != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dateOfJoining.equals(other.dateOfJoining))
            return false;
        if (designation == null) {
            if (other.designation != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!designation.equals(other.designation))
            return false;
        if (empID == null) {
            if (other.empID != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!empID.equals(other.empID))
            return false;
        if (monthlySalary != other.monthlySalary)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", empID=" + empID + ", designation=" + designation + ", DOJ=" + dateOfJoining
                + ", monthlySalary=" + monthlySalary + "]";
    }

}
```

I have created a separate class for the date of joining details.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class JoiningDate {

    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2019, 06, 15);
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2009, 06, 06);
    LocalDate date3 = LocalDate.of(2007, 05, 10);
    LocalDate date4 = LocalDate.of(2000, 05, 30);
    LocalDate date5 = LocalDate.of(1998, 07, 31);
    LocalDate date6 = LocalDate.of(1995, 12, 12);

}
```

Now I am trying to print the name of employees who joined in June using Hashmap, taking doj as key and name as value. But am unable to proceed. can someone please help?
Below is my code:-

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Employecomparable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        JoiningDate jd = new JoiningDate();
        List<Employee> listofemployee = new ArrayList<>();

        listofemployee.add(new Employee("Pink", "12345", Designation.ASE, jd.date1, 20000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("Red", "24680", Designation.SE, jd.date2, 30000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("Blue", "13570", Designation.SSE, jd.date3, 40000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("Orange", "13690", Designation.TL, jd.date4, 60000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("Green", "10909", Designation.AM, jd.date5, 800000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("Yellow", "89076", Designation.M, jd.date6, 2000));

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(today);
        Period time1 = Period.between(jd.date1, today);
        Period time2 = Period.between(jd.date2, today);
        Period time3 = Period.between(jd.date3, today);
        Period time4 = Period.between(jd.date4, today);
        Period time5 = Period.between(jd.date5, today);
        Period time6 = Period.between(jd.date6, today);

        Map<LocalDate,String> hashmap =new HashMap<>();

        for(Employee employee: listofemployee) {
            LocalDate key = employee.getDOJ();
            String value = employee.getName();
            if (hashmap.containsKey(key)) {
                ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                list.add(employee);
                hashmap.put(key, value);
        }
            }
        System.out.println(hashmap);
```

Comment: Why don't you just check the month of their jioning date = 6 ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to just print names of employees who joined in June:

```
listofemployee.stream().filter(employee->employee.getDOJ().getMonth().equals(Month.JUNE)).map(employee.getName()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: And if you need to return it instead of ```.forEach(...);``` use ```.collect(Collectors.toList());```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(Employee employee: listofemployee) 
    {
        LocalDate key = employee.getDOJ();
        String value = employee.getName();
        if(key.getMonth() == 6 )
         {
            hashMap.put(key, value); //if the date of joining is same day and time it would replace, as map dont share dups.
          }

     }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this!. But actually it will work with (key.getMonthValue()==05) instead of if(key.getMonth() == 6 ).

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (Employee employee : listofemployee) {
        LocalDate key = employee.getDOJ();
        String value = employee.getName();
        if (key.getMonthValue() == 06) {
            hashmap.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hashmap);
```

But this wont work in case of duplicates